# Set line-height as a percentage relative to the parent element

Tags: css

I have a responsive element where its width and height will both scale. Inside this I have some text which I want to center vertically.

How can I set the text's `line-height` to be the same as its parent if I don't know the parent's height?

`line-height: 100%` is relative to the font's regular height so this doesn't help...

Comment: isn't the `em` unit type used for these cases?

Comment: I doubt you can achieve this without JS

Comment: Alas, `em` will only scale relatively to the font-size, not the parent element dimensions

Comment: See this explanation of the problem: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: Providing your actual code will surely help us to provide a specific-case answer

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here's another way to center an element vertically. I came across [this technique](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) some time ago. Basically it uses a pseudo element and vertical-align: middle.

```
.block::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Since it's 2019 already, you could also use flexbox to achieve this :)

To do so, add the following classes to the parent element:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm6txa18/1/)

Comment: Since it's 2019 and people are still using IE, this will not work in all conditions in IE unfortunately.

Comment: Don't listen to the naysayers. Anyone using IE should expect the internet to look like crap in 2019.

Comment: Since this is web development, you should provide some kind of graceful degradation for your uses that don't have flexbox. Totally agreed that it can look like crap in a visual-flourish sense, but it should still remain functional, usable and meaningful.

Comment: Flexbox is the way.  IE is officially deprecated.  However, this method does render text-overflow: ellipsis non-functional unfortunately, but that is a real edge-case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try putting the text inside another element, of which you know (or set) the size. Then setting relative positioning to it, top, left 50% and negative left and right margins.

[See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKh8P/1/)

The only problem is that this relies on a known/fixed textblock. If the text is variable, I'm afraid you will have to resort to using Javascript..

Answer (score 1):

Regarding hyperlinks:

I was having this problem regarding links in main menu. And since it was `<a>` in `<li>` tags I needed some surface for the links to be clickable/touchable(see [touch target size](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/accessible-styles)). 
So what I did was for the `<ul>` I set a fixed height(through it's parent in this case), the `<li>`-s are a percentage of it and the `<a>`-s have a min-height and line-height properties set to them and it's easy from there to set the top. The code:

```
.menu-header-main-container{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 160px;
}    
.menu-header-main-container ul.menu {
          height: 100%; }
          .menu-header-main-container ul.menu li {
            height: 33.33%;
            max-height: 110px; }
            .menu-header-main-container ul.menu li a {
              line-height: 40px;
              min-height: 40px;
              top: calc(50% - 20px);
              position: relative; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the line-height to 100% of the parent element's height with only CSS. Rather, you can use CSS to center an element vertically.

```css
.parent {
   height:150px;
   position:relative;
   border:1px solid #FDD;
}
.position-center {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="position-center">I am vertically centered element</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, 2022 and I don't think we have a decent way to do this still. What I used to do and I think is the less painful idea is to use a table for layout. Tables will naturally center text vertically, or you can use "vertical-align"

```
   <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center">
    <tr><td>Your text</td></tr>
   </table>
```

Not great, but at least you can center text without ever having to specify fixed heights.