# How to fill the entire space inside the div with link and center the link text vertically?

Tags: css

Creating div-size link is quite easy to do (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555663/982646) like centering text vertically inside div (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12686489/982646).

But how to combine those two?

If I set link width and height 100% it is not centered anymore.

Comment: Where is your code? Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you can set your parent div to `inline-block` so that the link will be the same size as it.

to vertically center the link, you can set the `line-height` of the container to be the same height as the link.

```
.container {
  line-height: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.link {
  height: 3em;
}
```

There are other ways to vertically center, but we need more information in order to give a more appropriate solution.

Here is an example for what I've explained: http://codepen.io/JKudla/pen/xqaLvy